# How to create vertices between intersecting edges?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, shortcut

In *Edit Mode*, how do you create vertices between intersecting edges?

[image]

Are there any shortcuts?

Answer (score 8):

Under *Active Tool and Workspace Settings*, enable *Auto Merge* and *Split Edges & Faces*. Then select any vertex part of any intersecting edge and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. This creates vertices between intersecting edges.

[image]

Comment: Wow! How many versions does this go back? For ever? I've never noticed it, and it could have saved so much time!

Comment: exactly!! i actually just discovered it thanks to the OP! :D

Comment: I've always used tinyCAD, but this is so much easier :D

Comment: @Robin Heh it's apparently there from Blender 2.81, how have I missed this? :))