# How to extrude an edge or vertices parallel to itself along its local axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges, extrude

I want to extrude this edge for example, straight in the direction shown in the image. I've tried double tapping the X,Y and Z keys and changing the "transform orientation" but none of that seems to work.

[image: image1]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559

Comment: Sadly no that doesn't work for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to Edge Select mode
- Select the edges of the triangle and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>.
- Select the edge reference for your new parallel edge
- Press double <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and slide the edge which is parallel and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
- Enable *Auto Merge* and *Split Edges & Faces* under *Active Tool and Workspace Settings*.
- Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to intersect the edges and create new vertices at intersection like demonstrated here: [How to create vertices between intersecting edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272048/how-to-create-vertices-between-intersecting-edges).

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry I guess the surrounding geometry gave the wrong impression because thats not what I'm trying to do. I wanted to accurately extrude the highlighted edge straight along the direction shown in the image, while in side view mode. Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/UaUPNVZ Kinda like, extruding straight along it's own local axis

Comment: the geometry doesnt matter, it's the same procedure as demonstrated in the gif. select those 3 edges and duplicate them then select the edge and press GG to move it parrallelly and follow the same steps.