# Intersection line between surfaces

Tags: path, intersection

I am new to using Blender, I am wondering if there is a way to easily get the intersection path between two planes as an object. So far what I've done is use the intersect (knife) tool and then manually delete all the vertices, edges and faces until I'm left with just the path, but doing this is quite laborious with complex surfaces.
Thank you very much for your ideas.

Edit:In the example image, I would look to get the marked area as a path.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You mean you did it [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280275/142292) right? I think that is the only way you described. Also you can try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/272058/142292

Comment: Yes you are right, I am doing it in a similar way, only that the example you give me is of surfaces on the same plane, I did not clarify that I am working with surfaces on different planes. But I guess that also applies

Comment: I see you updated the image, it is the same procedure, doesn't matter how you position the planes.

Comment: why do you say that it's laborious? Once you've done the Intersect (Knife) you just need to select the new edge, Ctrl i to invert the selection, then delete?

Comment: I say it's laborious because the surfaces I'm using are more complex than the example, with loops and small details, as well as the resulting path, so it takes time for me to select specific things. It is true that I was selecting the things that I want to delete instead of the path and then inverting the selection so your suggestion can make that job easier for me. As I said, I am new and sometimes I can get complicated in simple tasks, I will continue learning, thank you both very much for your patience and your comments.