# Preserving the width of a rectangular shape when extruding geometry at different angles

Tags: geometry, topology, 2d

I am using Blender to create typography and 2D designs with basic flat shapes. I really like the general workflow for this; here's an example of one I made recently to get an idea of my goal.

[image]

Right now, I'm working with rectangles rotated at 90 and 45 degree increments, but I have a problem that relates to the geometry and topology of my shapes.

[image]

In the above image, I have a flat plane in top-down view.

- Figure 1 extrudes the bottom edge of the rectangle, resulting in a parallelogram, which has less width visually.
- Figure 2 duplicates and rotates the rectangle, producing the correct width, but the shapes are separated.
- Figure 3 is the desired topology with 1 connected shape, but I had to achieve it through careful manual editing.

Is there a process I can use to properly achieve the shape in figure 3? I haven't been able to figure this out...

Comment: Hello and welcome. very simple, in figure 2 just create a vertex at the intersection with this method https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/272048/142292 and then u can select 2 vertices and press `j` to split the geometry with that slanting edge. then dissolve the other edges with `x` > dissolve

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you! This works great, but I wonder if there's a less destructive way to achieve this geometry? Is there an easy way to achieve this without additional editing?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*, select your edge and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Extrude*:

[image]

Then set the *Width* value in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: oooh thank you. I'll try this out

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but the easiest way I found was the following:

Model it as you had been in figure 2...
Once you're happy with the design, create a plane that is bigger than the entire design.
[image]

Then use `Knife Project` to cut your design into the plane and you'll end up with this mess...
[image]

Then, delete the outer 4 vertices that formed the original plane (this has just really been an easy way to get verts at the intersections of all the lines, you might know a better way??)
[image]

Next, use the MACHIN3tools addon (which is free) to do a cleanup and you'll be left with just the perimeter
[image]

Finally hit `CTRL T` to triangulate your mesh, then `ALT J` to make quads and you should be good to go.
[image]

Comment: This also seems like a great alternative, thanks!