How to remove internal vertices, edges, and faces in a 2d geometry such that I am left with only a single largest face?
allow me to provide some incentive of doing what I am doing, so that if you see a better method, please let me know and thank you beforehand.
I have an stl file extracted directly from a video game containing a spaceship model. It is however quite complicated and messy and unsuitable for 3d printing. I am trying to slice the model into many layers, and then extrude each layer to get an approximate shape of the model that's much cleaner and easier to work with.
I create a plane and intersected it with the model to get a geometry as shown in the screenshot。 
However, if I zoom in I have vertices and edges that lies on the internal face as shown here:

Is there a quick way to dissolve all the internal vertices instead of selecting them individually and manually? Thank you.

I would recommend beforehand (1) to merge by distance vertices with a threshold based on the resolution of the 3D printer (2) to limited dissolve the faces because most of the STL triangles are split quads. This should greatly simplified the model, before trying to slice it.

Duplicate to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272048/how-to-create-vertices-between-intersecting-edges

If you have overlapping faces you can activate the Auto Merge and Split Edges and Faces option, then press G and Enter right away, it will remove these faces:

Then press X > Limited Dissolve to remove the inner vertices:

Result:

